# After splitting database importing excel files gives error 2950

Tags: ms-access

Before splitting my database I was using a macro for importing excel file to my table and it was okey.
Now after splitting database when I use that macro from front-end I got error:

```
    You cannot record your changes because a value you entered violates the 
  settings defined for this table or list (for example, a value is less than
   the minimum or greater than the maximum). Correct the error and try again."
   The error number on the Macro Single Step pop-up is 2950.
```

when i use macro from back-end it does not have problem and works.

please help because i need importing from front-end.

equivalent VBA code for macro i have used is like below, it works from back-end and gives error from the front-end:

```
  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 8, "Rep_Indicator", "E:\Rep_Indicator", True, ""
```

Comment: Provide code for analysis.

Comment: i added equivalent VBA code of my macro

Comment: Aside from lack of file extension on the workbook name, see nothing wrong with code. It works for me, imports into linked tables in frontend. Cannot replicate issue.

Comment: Cross-post http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=67906